# Wordpress how to remove word Category from the post

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress 
How to remove word **Category** from the post?
How to remove word **Tags** from the post?

[image: snap shot]

Comment: Maybe with the relevant code inside category.php or single.php (in /wp-content/themes/your-theme/), we can be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `categories` and `tags` are generated by two functions and these are

```
the_category()
the_tags()
```

These functions remain within the loop on the `index.php` or a partial template file which probably added using `get_template_part()` so, look for thsee functions in your appropriate template files and search for these functions and there you will find that these (`Category` and `Tag`) words are hard coded, so delete those words or just find for these words in you template files.

Look template files in `wp-content/themes/themeFolderName` and start from `index.php` file. Look for these words within following code

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    // find between something like these
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are using the "Twenty Thirteen" theme for your site.
Open your `content.php`. The following code is responsible to display tags and Categories.

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <?php twentythirteen_entry_meta(); ?>
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</div>
```

Just comment this line. Your problem will be solved if you are using Twenty Thirteen theme.

If you provide your theme name, I will be able to say clearly to remove which tags and categories.